# Не работает preventDefault() через событие onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма:

```
<form onclick="editMainForm(this)" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

И ajax отправка этой формы:

```
function editMainForm(i) {
    // i.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/edit-main-form-script',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(i).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data.status) {
                // Вывод ОК
            } else {
                // Вывод Ошибки
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Проблема:
когда `preventDefault` закомменчен, то данные с формы отправляются, но не убирается перезагрузка страницы (это понятно). Но если раскомментировать `preventDefault`, то у меня стираются все данные при повторной отправке формы, и всё равно повторяется отправка формы при перезагрузке страницы.

Как я понял, было бы хорошо, если бы оно работало так - `onclick="editMainForm(event,this)"`. Но так оно тем более не работает.

То есть, мне нужно воспользоваться и event и this, а указать я этого в событие onclick не могу.

Comment: «Но так оно тем более не работает» — почему не работает? Так оно тем более должно работать.

Comment: Почему отправка формы вообще происходит на клик по форме, а не на сабмит формы? В чем смысл?

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли! У меня не работало `onclick="editMainForm(event,this)"`, так как я вешал на форму а не на button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странно вешать `onclick` на саму форму, а не на кнопку. На мой взгляд проще добавить кнопку типа submit и повесить событие `submit` на форму, а в js обработать подтверждение формы. Там же и сделать `preventDefault`

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '../scripts/edit-main-form-script',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(e.target).serialize(), // сериализация данных с формы
    success: function(data){
        if (data.status) {
            // Вывод ОК
        } else {
            // Вывод Ошибки
        }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<form id="form" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Да, я понимаю что это работает. Но этот код не работает с динамически загруженным контентом. У меня есть много разных форм, которые загружаются в определенный блок при нажатии на кнопки меню (пример - в соцсети ВК страница редактирования). И мне надо именно с помощью события onclick. Впрочем, я понял свою ошибку на счёт того, что я вешал событие на форму а не на submit. Спасибо вам. Ниже я напишу код, как именно мне нужно было.

Comment: @Amanek вы написали точно то же самое, что описано в этом ответе, только другим способом

Comment: Всё верно, только ваш способ в моем случае с динамическим контентом не будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не вешайте события на form!

Решение:

```
<form id="editMainForm" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <button type="submit" onclick="editMainForm(event,this)">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function editMainForm(i) {
    i.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/edit-main-form-script',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#editMainForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data.status) {
                // Вывод ОК
            } else {
                // Вывод Ошибки
            }
        }
    });
};
```